# R - write function and allow user input to name data frame column within function

Tags: r

I have written the following function:

```
create_dls <- function(injury_type, col1, col2){ 
    injuries_10 = subset(dl2010, dl2010$Location %in% injury_type)
    injuries_11 = subset(dl2011, dl2011$Location %in% injury_type)
    on2010 = c()
    on2011 = c()
    for (mlbid in starting_pitchers$shared_players.MLBID){
        if (mlbid %in% injuries_10$MLBID){
            on2010 = c(on2010, 1)}
        else {
            on2010 = c(on2010, 0)}
        if (mlbid %in% injuries_11$MLBID){
            on2011 = c(on2011, 1)}
        else {
            on2011 = c(on2011, 0)}}
   sp_predictor$col1 <<- on2010
   sp_predictor$col2 <<- on2011
}
```

When I run the code as follows:

```
create_dls(shoulder_injuries, "2010_sDL", "2011_sDL")
```

I get the output:

```
> head(sp_predictor)
  starting_pitchers.shared_players.MLBID col1 col2
1                                 112020    0    0
2                                 115399    0    0
3                                 115817    0    0
4                                 117955    0    0
5                                 119154    0    0
6                                 123801    0    0
```

What I want to do is have the column names of sp_predictor be user inputs in the function, instead of being named col1 and col2. Just for reference, I have tried the following, which did not work.

```
function(injury_type, col1="Column 1 Name", col2="Column 2 Name")

x=toString(col1)
sp_predictor$x <<- on2010

x=get("col1")
sp_predictor$x <<- on2010
```

None of the above has worked. (note: this is my first question posted on StackOverflow, if I've asked this question wrong please please let me know!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `[[` instead of `$` when making your assignments to `sp_predictor`

```
create_dls <- function(injury_type, col1, col2){ 
    injuries_10 = subset(dl2010, dl2010$Location %in% injury_type)
    injuries_11 = subset(dl2011, dl2011$Location %in% injury_type)
    on2010 = c()
    on2011 = c()
    for (mlbid in starting_pitchers$shared_players.MLBID){
        if (mlbid %in% injuries_10$MLBID){
            on2010 = c(on2010, 1)}
        else {
            on2010 = c(on2010, 0)}
        if (mlbid %in% injuries_11$MLBID){
            on2011 = c(on2011, 1)}
        else {
            on2011 = c(on2011, 0)}}
   sp_predictor[[col1]] <<- on2010
   sp_predictor[[col2]] <<- on2011
}
```